# Jump to another scene detecting a rigidbody

Tags: c#, unityscript

I am making a little game in `c#` on `unity 5`, and until now I have almost everything. How do I jump to another scene on detecting a rigidbody?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Please go through [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I just don't have any code it's just that.
Our friend Adrew just help me out, but an parsen error come out saying that the void can't be after a public in this case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in one of your game object's scripts, put:

```
public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    Application.LoadLevel(nextLevel);
}
```

so implementation would look as such:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class BotonIrAInstrucciones : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () { }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () { }

    public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("Next Level");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do i put that?
In wich part of this?


`using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BotonIrAInstrucciones : MonoBehaviour {
 
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
  
 }
 
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
  
 }`

Comment: put it into the class of the object that will either hit something or get hit by something.

Comment: i said you put it inside of the class, so you have `public class BotonIrAInstrucciones : MonoBehaviour` and you make sure its between the `{` and `}` from that class level. you do not put it inside of any methods in that class and you don't put it outside of a class.

Comment: send me the entire text as you would do it, it keep throwing errors

Comment: Now don't have errors just don't want to work. It's like if can not be detected

Comment: BotonIrAInstrucciones game object needs a rigidbody component and both objects need to have colliders

Comment: i have it like that, but i dunno

Comment: Are you putting your scene's name instead of Next Level?

Comment: Your colliders aren't set to triggers?

Comment: Yes, but anyways onlything i do setting them as trigger is that my character sink into the floor

Comment: Yes but oncollisionenter also wouldn't execute if one was a trigger. Anyways, you aren't moving your character with transform directly right? You must be using rigidbody addforce or velocity. Also put `Debug.Log("asdf");` above the loadlevel command and tell me if it prints.

Comment: Can you edit it and send it to me?
What do i put between the ´(" and ")´

Comment: Edited. No need to change it, just let me know if "asdf" gets printed to your console upon a collision.

Comment: You did it my friend :D the error was that i couldn't read that the 2nd scene wasn't added to the build settings 'cause there were 2 audio listeners.
THANK YOU

Comment: Okay good, so delete the debug part otherwise it will slow your game.